# Tabs вкладки фиксированного размера

Tags: android, tabs

ЕстьViewPager. 3 вкладки. Хочу сделать как в Snapster одна вкладка большая, и две меньше, и чтобы они распределялись на весь экран.

Comment: Если хотите - сделайте. В чем вопрос/проблема?

Comment: Не знаю как. Сейчас у меня tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
 Равномерное распределение вкладок.

Comment: Покажите скриншот желаемого результата